# Earning a certification

Tags: magento-1.9

I've been working with Magento since April and plan on starting to study so that I can write the exam soon.

I was trying to find out where/when I could take exams to see what kind of schedule I would be on.

I found the FAQ - https://magento.com/training/catalog/certification/faq and have located the nearest test center to me, but when I try to view the page where I can register (http://www.webassessor.com/magento) I get a 404 - does anyone know any other way I can schedule a test, please?

Answer (score 1):

purchase exam voucher from [here](https://magento.com/training/catalog/certification)..  if you already purchased voucher

than visit [here](https://www.webassessor.com/wa.do?page=publicHome&branding=MAGENTO)

For 
**Test taker account creation
Exam registration and scheduling**

Contact **certification@magento.com**  or your test center

for more visit [here](https://www.webassessor.com/wa.do?page=help&tabs=1&branding=MAGENTO)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the exam voucher please go through the link for finding nearest test center https://www.kryteriononline.com/Locate-Test-Center

If you don't have the voucher ,you can purchase it from here https://u.magento.com/certification-solution-specialist#.WAS78bMaY3U
and select the nearest test center from the above link.

If you have questions about creating an account or scheduling an exam ,please  email  at certification@magento.com.

Answer (score 0):

1. On very first purchase exam voucher from https://magento.com/training/catalog/certification after that .
2. Go to here https://www.webassessor.com/wa.do? and create a new account or login if you have an account
3. Then login and after that click on `register for new examination`
4. Select your exam
5. Select country ,state and search
6. Select your nearest testing center and click on select
7. You will get the available date and time select your preferred date and time and complete your other process